# does vaadin video component support preload attribute

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I have more than 10 mp4 videos which I am tying to embed in my web application using vaadin video component. When I run my application on Edge/IE the vidoes work fine, but on chrome they dont. Its known issue with chrome where if the page has more than 6-8 mp4 videos, it hangs as it tried to preload all of them together.
I was wondering if the video component provide me option to set the preload to none. I can see the mediabase has this option
https://vaadin.com/api/7.6.7/index.html?com/google/gwt/media/client/MediaBase.html
But I dont see it for video.
Also I found another link where they seems to do the fix https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/5178 , but couldnt make it work.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until the commit/PR in your linkgets merged, it does not in 7 or 8.

However, you can use an AbstractExtension and AbstractExtensionConnector to accomplish this.

**The AbstractExtension**

```
package com.my.package;

import com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector;
import com.vaadin.server.AbstractExtension;
import com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent;
public class VideoPreloadExtension extends AbstractExtension {

    public VideoPreloadExtension() {
    }

    public VideoPreloadExtension(AbstractClientConnector target) {
        super(target);
    }

    public void extend(AbstractComponent component) {
        super.extend(component);
    }

}
```

**The AbstractExtensionConnector**

```
package com.my.package.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;
import com.vaadin.client.ComponentConnector;
import com.vaadin.client.ServerConnector;
import com.vaadin.client.extensions.AbstractExtensionConnector;
import com.my.package.VideoPreloadExtension;
import com.vaadin.shared.ui.Connect;

@Connect(VideoPreloadExtension.class)
public class VideoPreloadConnector extends AbstractExtensionConnector {

    @Override
    protected void init() {
        super.init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void extend(ServerConnector target) {
        // Get the extended widget
        final Widget widget = ((ComponentConnector) target).getWidget();
        widget.getElement().setAttribute("preload","auto");
    }
}
```

**Usage is as follows:**

```
Video image = new Video();
VideoPreloadExtension ext = new VideoPreloadExtension();
ext.extend(image);
```

**Some Notes (because vaadin can be a pain at times)**

1. If you have a library module already,  its best to add the above classes to it.
2. Confirm that the module you add these classes to has the following dependency add so the widgetset will get compiled:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
       <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. Remember that the `VideoPreloadConnector` needs to be in a package name that ends with ".client".

Here is a screenshot of an inspect element from chrome of it working:

[image: screenshot of an inspect element from chrome]

HTHs!